# Best way to delimit a string and store into array in C++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm trying to delimit a string following the format
STRING1->STRING2 where the "->" is the delimiter and the STRING1 can be stored into a cell in the array and STRING2 can be stored into the next consecutive cell. What's the best way to go about coding this? Thanks!

Comment: I'd say for parsing a `std::regex` would provide the easiest way to realize this. There would be simpler solutions using a single character delimiter.

Comment: Try using split function

Comment: Imran, split doesn't exist so easily as Java in C++.

Comment: @Imran What's _split function_? I don't know any [c++ standard function](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=split), named so.

Comment: Would anyone mind providing a REGEX split example for the delimiter of "->"

Comment: @ryan Well, you can also write a little parsing loop on a whole line string (char by char), with a state handling the `'-' ` and `'>'` characters.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm see this link, you should find a hint. Or you also can follow  πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @ryan _"a REGEX split example"_ Something like `((->)?([^->]*))*` (not tested)?

Comment: @Imran `strtok()` might introduce reentrancy problems.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use sscanf:

```
char input[] = "123->456";
sscanf("%d->%d", &array[0], &array[1]);
```

Using iostreams, it's a little clumsier (but still entirely possible):

```
char ign1, ign2;

istringstream input("123->456");
input >> array[0] >> ign1 >> ign2 >> array[1];
assert(ign1=='-');
assert(ign2=='>');
```

There is a slight difference between these as written though--the C++ version will accept input that has white-space before, in the middle of, or after the delimiter, such as `123 -   >     456`, and the C version won't. If you want the C version to do so, it's trivial to add that (change the format string to `"%d - >%d"`) but getting the C++ version to not do so makes it even clumsier:

```
input >> array[0];
input.read(ign1);
input.read(ign2);
input >> array[1];
```